# Nhibernate Stored Procedure Mapping in xml file clarification

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Can anyone tell where to map Stored-Procedures exactly in Nhibernate.

In class hbm.xml file or newly declared file(hbm.xml) especially for Stored Procedures???

can u tell with reason??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I create a single XML file that contains ALL stored procedure calls, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">  
  <sql-query name="SummaryReport">  
    exec getSummaryReport  :productId  
  </sql-query>  
  <sql-query name="FullReport">  
    exec getFullReport  :productId  
  </sql-query>  
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and mark this as an embedded resource. I can then call me SP like this:-

```
var results = Session
  .GetNamedQuery("SummaryReport")
  .SetInt32("productId", productId);
  .SetResultTransformer(
    new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(SummaryReport)));
return results.List<SummaryReport>();
```

This works fine for me but there really isn't a recommended way, its always down to what you feel is right for you.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. In our project we are mapping stored procedures in the same xml files of the classes, which consists the  details of table and it's specificaions. We are not taking new(i mean special) xml file for the mapping of the stored procedure in our project. Can u tell the difference between mapping stored procedure in special xml file only for SP's and mapping the stored procedure in normal xml file, which was created for table mapping.......waiting for ur answer

Comment: There is no difference. Both will work the same. Its upto you and how you want to orgnanise things.